# Finding all triples of numbers with the following divisibility

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Could somebody tell me how to tackle this problem? I don’t know where to start with it. The problem was part of the Math Olympiad in Kazhakstan (or Kyrgistan, I keep forgetting…) this February, but there are no solutions online.

Find all triples $(x, y, z)$ of positive integers for which $$x|(y + 1)$$ $$y|(z + 1)$$ $$z|(x + 1)$$
holds.

Comment: In general, $a \mid b \Rightarrow a \leq b$.  Using this, the divisibility relations give you pretty tight constraints on $x, y, z$.

Comment: @Robert Shore we know $x\leq(y+1)\leq(z+2)\leq(x+3)$, so we see that $x=y=z$ could be a solution. Now is that the only option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $3$ divisibility requirements, and that $(x,y,z)$ are positive integers, means there are positive integers $m_1$, $m_2$ and $m_3$ such that

$$y + 1 = m_1 x \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$z + 1 = m_2 y \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$x + 1 = m_3 z \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

There is a symmetry with each equation above being of the form of a variable plus $1$ equaling a multiple of another variable. With some $m_1 = a_1$ and $x = v_1$, then \eqref{eq1A} gives $y = a_1 v_1 - 1 = v_2$. Then with some $m_2 = a_2$, \eqref{eq2A} gives $z = a_2 v_2 - 1 = v_3$. Finally, with some $m_3 = a_3$, \eqref{eq3A} gives $x = a_3 v_3 - 1$, which leads back to \eqref{eq1A}.

Note we could have started with $a_1$ and $v_1$ in \eqref{eq2A} (or \eqref{eq3A}) instead, and then used \eqref{eq3A} and \eqref{eq1A} (or \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A}) with the next $2$ multiplier values of $a_2$ and $a_3$. This indicates there's a rotational symmetry, i.e., if $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ is a solution, then so is moving each value's position to the right (or left), and "rotating" the position at the end (or start) to the start (or end), i.e., $(z_1, x_1, y_1)$ and $(y_1, z_1, x_1)$ are also solutions.

Next, adding the $3$ equations above gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x + y + z + 3 & = m_1 x + m_2 y + m_3 z \\
3 & = (m_1 - 1)x + (m_2 - 1)y + (m_3 - 1)z
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Note the $3$ terms on the right are all non-negative integers. There are $3$ cases regarding the number of $0$ terms on the right side to consider:

**Case #$1$:**

None of the terms are $0$. Thus, they each must be $1$, i.e., $m_1 = m_2 = m_3 = 2$ and $x = y = z = 1$. This means the only the solution here is $(1,1,1)$.

**Case #$2$:**

Just one of the terms on the right of \eqref{eq4A} is $0$, say the first one. This gives $m_1 = 1$. Then one of the other terms must be $1$ and the final term must be $2$. Consider first $(m_2 - 1)y = 1$, which means $m_2 = 2$ and $y = 1$. From \eqref{eq2A}, this gives $z = 1$. Note we will also get $y = z = 1$ by having $(m_3 - 1)z = 1$ instead. With $m_1 = y = 1$, then \eqref{eq1A} gives $x = 2$. Thus, a solution is $(2,1,1)$, with the other $2$ associated ones being $(1,2,1)$ and $(1,1,2)$. Note this actually covers all of the possibilities for this case.

**Case #$3$:**

Here, $2$ of the terms on the right of \eqref{eq4A} are $0$, say the first $2$. This gives

$$m_1 = m_2 = 1, \; 3 = (m_3 - 1)z \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This results in $2$ possibilities. First, $z = 1$ and $m_3 - 1 = 3 \implies m_3 = 4$. From \eqref{eq3A}, this gives $x = 3$. Also, $m_1 = 1$ gives in \eqref{eq1A} that $y = 2$. Thus, a solution is $(3, 2, 1)$. Due to the rotational symmetry I mentioned (with this coming from the cases where either $m_2$ or $m_3$ are not $1$), the other $2$ related solutions are $(2, 1, 3)$ and $(1, 3, 2)$.

The other possibility from \eqref{eq5A} is $z = 3$ and $m_3 - 1 = 1 \implies m_3 = 2$. From \eqref{eq3A}, this gives $x = 5$. Also, $m_1 = 1$ gives from \eqref{eq1A} that $y = 4$. Thus, a solution is $(5, 4, 3)$. The other rotational related solutions are $(3, 5, 4)$ and $(4, 3, 5)$.

---

Altogether, the set of $(x,y,z)$ solutions are $\{(1,1,1)$, $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,1)$, $(2,1,1)$, $(1,3,2)$, $(2,1,3)$, $(3,2,1)$, $(3,5,4)$, $(4,3,5)$, $(5,4,3)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-Another way.

►Since $1$ is a trivial factor of all integer then $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$ is a solution.

►$x=y$ and $x|x+1$ implies clearly $x=1$ so looking for a solution $(1,1,z)$ we have $z=2$ from $z|x+1$. Thus $(1,1,2)$ (and its analogues $(1,2,1)$ and $(2,1,1)$) is a second solution and it remains to solve $x,y,z$ all three distinct.

►The given conditions imply $x\le y+1$ and similarly $y\le z+1$ and $z\le x+1$ from which we have $$z-1\le x\le y+1\le z+2$$ (and by symmetry $x-1\le y\le z+1\le x+2$ and $y-1\le z\le x+1\le y+2$).

It follows that for each fixed value of, say $z$, the other two distinct values of $x$ and $y$ must be either equal to $z-1$ or $z+1$ or $z+2$.

►The other few solutions can be easily calculated.